# Why can't I override Photon virtual functions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

This is my code

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
    {
        newPlayer.NickName = "hello";
        return;
    }
}
```

and then there is the photon file:

```
public class MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks : MonoBehaviourPun, IConnectionCallbacks , IMatchmakingCallbacks , IInRoomCallbacks, ILobbyCallbacks, IWebRpcCallback, IErrorInfoCallback
{
    public virtual void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
    {
    }
}
```

My code cannot access the function.

Does anyone know what is wrong with this and what I have to do to fix it?

Comment: what happens when you call `someClass.OnPlayerEnteredRoom` ? How are you calling it?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect a missing namespace.

While [`MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_mono_behaviour_pun_callbacks.html) is in the namespace `Photon.Pun`, the type [`Player`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_player.html) is in `Photon.Realtime`.

So either you need to add a

```
using Photon.Realtime;
```

or in case you have your own type somewher called `Player` as well either add

```
using Player = Photon.Realtime.Player;
```

or explicitly use

```
public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(PlaPhoton.Realtime.Player newPlayer)
{
    newPlayer.NickName = "hello";
    return;
}
```